# Trying to play a animation on scrolling down and rewind on scrolling up

Tags: html, css, animation, mp4

I am trying to play an MP4 video while scrolling down and then rewind it while scrolling up.

I currently have the video (of an animation) working with HTML CSS and JS.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small example to display with an image. like when you scroll down some animation will be shown and once you scroll back to up animation will be revert.

```
CSS STYLE:

.classname {
-webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.classname1 {
-webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation1;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation1 {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(20px);
}
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(20px);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
}
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(2) skew(0deg) translate(100px);
}
}
    
   
  **JAVASCRIPT PART**     

  var lastScrollTop = 0;
    document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ 
    var value = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (value > lastScrollTop){
        scrollDownAnnimation();
     } else {
        scrollUpAnnimation();
    }
    lastScrollTop = value <= 0 ? 0 : st;
    });
        
    function scrollDownAnnimation() {
    document.getElementById('img').className = 'classname';
    }
    function scrollUpAnnimation() {
    document.getElementById('img').className = 'classname1';
    }

  
 **HTML PART: Please make sure you have added page content so that scroll can come on page**   

 <div>
    <img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vghKS.png" width="328" height="328" />
</div>
```

For Demo: [DEMO](https://www.tnv24.com/scroll-animation)

Hope this help, Thanks!

Comment: If the answer is useful/helpful for you then, please upvote. Thanks!

Comment: I think Asker is trying to seek through frames of a video. It's a badly written question, with no working example of problem in a link or no code to recreate their problem...

Comment: PS: Maybe the answer is how to link the page's scroll point with video time point (so scrolling to 50% of page height is same as seeking to 50% of video duration). Not obvious what Asker has tried...